# Is there a way to listen to Microsoft AD logout session success in a webview?

Tags: react-native, webview, azure-active-directory

In a React Native App Microsoft's login form is used to log into the app through a webview. When logging out the users would be redirected to a React Native view again to be able to log back in (maybe with another account).

The problem is when the user selects an account to logout it hits a url with `logoutsession` that executes scripts (possibly removing cookies from the in-app browser) and if its not awaited on the redirected login screen they are auto logged in again into the same account.

Tried to use `CookieManager` from [rn-cookies](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cookies) to remove cookies but it seem to take effect once the app is reopened.

Is there a way to listen when the `sessionlogout` page finished executing scripts so the auth loop can be closed without closing the app?